# How to $watch dynamically created ng-model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Below is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat='department in vm.otherDepartments'>
                            <label class="checkbox-custom-labelother_label">
                                <div class="custom-label-div other_label">department.name</div>
                                <input type="text" name="vm.experience.custom" class="other_inputbox" ng-model="vm.experience.custom[department.id]" ng-required='!vm.experience.departments'>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Below is my controller code:

```
 $scope.$watch("vm.experience.custom", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('newValue:');
        console.log(newValue);
        vm.params.validateDepartments = _.filter(newValue, function (o) {
            console.log('OOOO:');
            console.log(o);
        });
    });
```

So when I change any of the input value $watch should be triggered. But that is not happening in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$watch is just a shallow watch by default.
you will have to set the third parameter of $watch to "true" in order to make it a deep watch - checking all subproperties of your object.
so you will have to make it

```
$scope.$watch ('property', function () {}, true);
```

in your case the $watch function will only be triggered if the value of .custom itself changes.